# Should I buffer my sensor before feeding it into an op amp or does the op amp buffer it for me

Tags: sensor, operational-amplifier, analog

I have a sensor which outputs 10mV pk-pk.. I want to amplify this with some non-inverting amplifiers but my question is:

Do I need to buffer the signal before I feed it into an op amp with gain, or does the gain op amp do the buffering as well?

Comment: What exactly do you think a "buffer" does?

Comment: Certain opamp configurations can actually bugger with your signal somewhat if it has a high output impedance, the standard non inverting configuration doesn't have this problem however.

Comment: I think it already provides appropriate buffering, that is one of the constructional requirements of an opamp, but why don't you try both and also tell us? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stay close to DC and this is a question of output impedance of your sensor.

If you use a simple inverting op-amp configuration like this, you will have R1 as load for your sensor output. Suppose you have R1=1K/R2=10K and 100R output impedance of your sensor. That would not give you 10x gain but more like 10/1.1 ~ 9x.

[image: Inverting configuration]

You can have a much higher impedance as "load" to your sensor by using a simple non-inverting configuration. That may be what you want to do in cases where your sensor has a fairly high output impedance.

See more in this question: [Mic preamp: Inverting or non-inverting op-amp configuration?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/46912/mic-preamp-inverting-or-non-inverting-op-amp-configuration)

I think you can answer the question simply by looking at the sensor output impedance (which may be expressed as some current/voltage at some load in the datasheet, but you get the idea).

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on what your sensor puts out. As indicated in the other answers...

If you need a very high input impedance you can look at a non inverting configuration. The input impedance will be very high as its just the OpAmps input impedance.

An inverting OpAmp circuit has an input impedance equal to the input resistor. R1 in Rolf's drawing. You can set this value high so it's probably going to work fine.

The key is that in normal configurations the negative input pin is a virtual ground, since it's held there by the output though R2. This make the input look like R1 is tied to ground, so it's setting the impedance.

Answer (score 0):

Check your sensor's and your opamp's datasheet:

1. The opamp's internal resistance should be much (suppose at least 10 times) higher than the sensor's internal resistance
2. The DC input current drawn by the opamp should not produce an untolerable constant error to your measurement.